# Incomplete C recursive function. I do not know how to implement correctly

Tags: c, recursion

I need to implement a recursive function in C that can simulate a pstree, that is, imagine the numbers below as a process:

```
1 (father)
   2 (child of 1)
   3 (child of 1)
     4 (son of 3)
       5 (child of 4)
     6 (child of 3)
```

etc....

```c
void imprime_Pstree(int i, int ntabs)
{
    int k = 0, j = 0, quantProc = 0;
    int procAtual;

    // Prints the number of tabs
    for(k = 0; k < ntabs; k++)
        printf("\t");

    quantProc = preenche_vetor(i);

    // Prints the process name
    imprimeNomeProcesso(i);


    for(j = 0; j < quantProc; j++) {

        imprime_Pstree(processos[j], ntabs+1);
    }

}
```

But it prints only the parent (called the recursive function) and the child of the same, who has no other children.
 
I know that another call to the recursive function is missing back in the parent of the previous child, but how?

---

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int processos[1000];

void limpa_vetor() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        processos[i] = 0;
}

int preenche_vetor(int proc) {
    char path[50];
    char string[100];
    int i, j = 0, cont = 0;
    char temp;
    FILE *arq;

    limpa_vetor();

    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/task/%d/children", proc, proc);
    arq = fopen(path, "r");

    if (arq != NULL)
    {
        limpa_vetor();

        fscanf(arq, "%s", string);
        while(strcmp(string, "") != 0)
        {
            if(feof(arq)) break;
            processos[j] = atoi(string);
            cont++;

            fscanf(arq, "%c", &temp);
            fscanf(arq, "%s", string);
            j++;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}

void imprimeNomeProcesso(int proc) {
    char path[50];
    char string[100];
    int i, j = 0;
    char temp;
    FILE *arq;

    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/stat", proc);
    arq = fopen(path, "r");

    if (arq != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(arq, "%s", string);
        while(strcmp(string, "") != 0)
        {
            if(feof(arq)) break;

            if(j == 1)
            {
                printf("%s ", string);
                break;
            }

            fscanf(arq, "%c", &temp);
            fscanf(arq, "%s", string);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void imprime_Pstree(int i, int ntabs)
{
    int k = 0, j = 0, quantProc = 0;
    int procAtual;

    // Imprime a quantidade de tabs
    for(k = 0; k < ntabs; k++)
        printf("\t");

    quantProc = preenche_vetor(i);

    // Imprime o nome do processo
    imprimeNomeProcesso(i);


    for(j = 0; j < quantProc; j++) {

        imprime_Pstree(processos[j], ntabs+1);
    }

}

int main()
{
    imprime_Pstree(1, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems that `processos` is  a global var that contains the list of all children of `i`. That doesn't work in a recursive function. The recursive call will overwrite the array. You must make it a local var and pass it to he function that has to assign the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`processos` is a global var that contains the list of all children of i. That doesn't work in a recursive function. The recursive call will overwrite the array. You must make it a local var and pass it to the function that has to assign the values:

```
void imprime_Pstree(int i, int ntabs)
{
    int k = 0, j = 0, quantProc = 0;
    int procAtual;
    int processos[1000];    // <-- have a local array

    // Imprime a quantidade de tabs
    for(k = 0; k < ntabs; k++)
        printf("\t");

    // pass that array to preenche_vetor()
    quantProc = preenche_vetor(i, processos );

   // Imprime o nome do processo
   imprimeNomeProcesso(i);


   for(j = 0; j < quantProc; j++) {

        imprime_Pstree(processos[j], ntabs+1);
   }   

}
```

Of course you must also change the signature of preenche_vetor() and must do the initialisation() there.

**Edit**
As @Aconcagua ha suggested, it would be even better to determine the number of children first and then declare and fill a VLA

Comment: Fixed size arrays give me a bad feeling in such situations - either they are far too large, or they don't suffice the needs. I personally would prefer a getter for the number of child processes and use this one to initialise a VLA...

Comment: @Aconcagua yes that yould be an improvement. I just wanted to change as little as possible to point out the core of the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

```
quantProc = preenche_vetor(i);
```

Well, now we have a number of processes.

```
for(j = 0; j < quantProc; j++)
{
    imprime_Pstree(processos[j], ntabs+1);
}
```

Two possible scenarios:

1. `processos` contains a list all currently active processes in your system. Then you'd be iterating over the processes just as they are found in the array, i. e. if any process has at least one child, the first process in your system (linux: would be root process with id 0, which normally never dies) would always be printed as child of your current process. You need a separate list containing the child process ids you can iterate over!
2. `processos` is filled by `preenche_vetor` function with the child processes for the given process id. Then any recursive call to `imprime_Pstree` will overwrite the child process list of the callee (as `preenche_vetor` is called again). Solution: you need to provide a separate array for each of the recursive calls.